# Is It possible in JSplumb to change the shape of the link connecting the nodes?

Tags: jsplumb, flowchart

Is It possible in JSplumb to change the shape of the link connecting the nodes ? JSPlumb connects like the red line , while i want the user to change the shape to connect like the green line (sample diagram)

[sample diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRb4T.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing **stokeStyle** of connection's **paintStyle**

You can set it while the connection is created or you can change it later ("Change Color" button on example.).

Here is the example;  https://jsfiddle.net/mokarakaya/6yfbm2et/

```
paintStyle:{lineWidth:3,strokeStyle:"green"}
```

or;

```
connection.setPaintStyle({lineWidth:3,strokeStyle:'blue'});
```